# Does a Linux based openLDAP server have an _ldap._tcp DNS service record?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I know that you can query the _ldap._tcp. for an AD service and it will return the hosts which are the LDAP servers.  Does the same thing work on Linux?  If it is not the default, how do you turn it on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not turn it on.
You could, in your DNS server, create a record that will refer to your openLDAP server.

-jim